# Gatling Recorder gRPC HTTP/2 support

Tags: grpc, load-testing, gatling

I want to load test a web application server which communicates through [gRPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRPC) (which uses HTTP/2 for transport) with the clients.

It seems that [Gatling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gatling_(software)) extended by the plugin [Gatling-gRPC](https://github.com/phiSgr/gatling-grpc) would be perfect for this. Among other things Gatling provides a [Recorder](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/recorder/) which helps quickly generate scenarios by acting as a HTTP proxy between the client and the server.

Question 1: Is it possible to use the Gatling Recorder for recording the communication through the gRPC protocol?

Question 2: Is it possible to use the Gatling Recorder for recording the communication through the underlying HTTP/2 protocol?

I have tried already the Gatling Recorder to record the gRPC communication without success :-( Maybe caused by wrong configuration of the recorder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to record gRPC with Gatling's recorder atm:

- it doesn't support HTTP/2
- it doesn't support gatling-grpc which is a third-party plugin work (there's some ongoing work to contribute it upstream)